# functor chaining function for c++20

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20

How might `chain_apply()` be improved?

```
auto chain_apply(auto&& a, auto&& ...f)
{
  auto const execute([&]<auto I>(auto&& self)
    {
      if constexpr(I)
      {
        return std::get<I>(
          std::forward_as_tuple(f...))(
          self.template operator()<I - 1>(self)
        );
      }
      else
      {
        return std::apply(
          std::get<0>(std::forward_as_tuple(f...)),
          std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)
        );
      }
    }
  );

  return execute.template operator()<sizeof...(f) - 1>(execute);
}
```

[Usage](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qfYF1PM4IJtzmIUn):

```
int main()
{
  auto const inc([](auto const i) noexcept
    {
      return i + 1;
    }
  );

  std::cout << chain_apply(std::tuple(0), inc, inc, inc, inc) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

No pipe operator this time, but consider:

```
std::tuple(0) | inc | inc | inc | inc;
```

Comment: [here](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/invoke.cpp) is a more complete version, with the possibility of `void` and `tuple<>` returns (`tuple<>` returns are auto-applied to the next function in the chain).

Answer (score 2):

## A simpler approach

You can do this without packing the callables into a tuple and without using a recursive lambda. Consider:

```
auto chain_apply(auto&& a, auto&& f, auto&& ...fs)
{
  if constexpr(sizeof...(fs)) {
      return chain_apply(std::forward_as_tuple(std::apply(f, a)), fs...);
  } else {
      return std::apply(f, a);
  }
}
```

(Some `std::forward()`s omitted for the sake of clarity.)

## It's not very useful to chain `std::apply()`

`std::apply()` is used to unpack a tuple and apply it to a callable. However, the return value of most functions you would want to use is not a `std::tuple`, instead it is a single value. So you can forward that as a tuple of one element, but that means you can only chain multiple callables if each one after the first only takes a single parameter.

If the function you pass does return a `std::tuple`, you pack that tuple in another tuple. You could make `chain_apply()` detect if the return value after applying a callable is a tuple, and if so not wrap it but pass it to the next function, but that seems like a heuristic that might fail in some situations.

If it only makes sense for `a` to be a tuple with one element, then you could ask yourself if it needed to be a `std::tuple` to begin with. I would also much rather be able to write:

```
std::cout << chain_apply(0, inc, inc, inc, inc) << '\n';
```

Comment: In my defense, [`std::apply()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) could also be improved in this way.

Comment: Well, there's [`std::invoke()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) if you don't want to pass a `std::tuple`. Maybe all this will be moot in C++23 or C++26 if we get [UFCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax).

Comment: Oh no, I'd like to chain coroutines :) That's what I'm working on.